# Stop Excel wrapping values that contain carriage returns with double quotes

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains various rows of data (some which contain carriage returns) and a cell at the end of each row that uses a formula to generate a JSON string. However, a problem has arisen where, if a row contains a cell that contains a carriage return, it will add double quotes, as well as quoting the entire row when I paste it into my text editor.

I’ve come to learn this is Excel’s default behaviour. How can I disable it or work around?

And don’t tell me to find a different solution. I would if I had the option but I’m working in a corporate environment, where I’ve been given the spreadsheet to work with.

Comment: Do you have other double quotes in your JSON string you need to keep? If not you could run a find and replace once you paste into your text editor.

Comment: @AndiMohr Yes. The string delimiters for each and every string.

Comment: If my answer below is no good you could try this - add a marker string at the front of each line so you get something like this "ZZZZZZZZZZZ your string here". Then you can do a find and replace on `"/n"ZZZZZZZZZZZ `  if you follow me!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not too tricky if you're happy to lose the carriage return. Simply wrap your line aggregation formula in this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C2,CHAR(10)," ")
```

where C2 is where you've placed your string aggregation formula - you could of course enter your entire string formula here instead.

This simply replaces the carriage return `CHAR(10)` with a space. When you copy into a text editor the offending double quotes no longer appear.